# Splunk Query to find all the occurrences of a Boolean key value pair in logs over a period of time

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

Given below is a snippet of splunk event. My requirement is to find all the occurrences of **"isOutstanding": true**. Here the point to note is that one event may/may not have multiple occurrences. Need to find the total count from multiple events over a period of time.

```
{
  \"school\": {
    \"schoolId\": \"1\",
    \"schoolName\": \"SchoolX\",
    \"schoolType\": \"private\",
    \"students\": [
      {
        \"id\": \"1\",
        \"isOutstanding\": true,
        
      },
      {
        \"id\": \"2\",
        \"isOutstanding\": false,
        
      },
      {
        \"id\": \"3\",
        \"isOutstanding\": false,
        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The below Splunk query **index=myIndex  "isOutstanding":true** gives the count of events having **"isOutstanding": true**. But it doesn't consider the count of multiple occurrences in one event.
How can I get the count of all the occourences in an event? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the query for my requirement

```
index=myindex sourcetype=mysourceType 
| rex max_match=0 "(?<isOutstanding>isOutstanding\\\\\":true)"
|  stats count(isOutstanding) as total
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the `rex` feature to extract all instances of the pattern you're looking for, then use the `mvcount` to count them.

```
    index=syslog sourcetype=testing isOutstanding
    | rex field=school max_match=0 "(?<outs>isOutstanding\": true") 
    | eval total=mvcount(outs)
    | table total
```